# how to make a meaning of memory statistics section of Nsight profiling?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, nvidia, nsight

i'm using Geforce 820m with

- GPU Clock rate:                                1124 MHz (1.12 GHz)
- memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz
- Memory Bus Width:                              64-bit
- L2 Cache Size:                                 1048576 bytes
  i used Nsight performance analysis to profile the memory transaction of my application and get to the memory statistics, which shows something like this
  [image: memory stats].

how could i know if i am achieving the max memory throughput i can get from this card or not? is there a percentage value like occupancy but for memory throughput? or how can i make use/meaning of these numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The peak theoretical device memory bandwidth on your GPU is given by

900MHz * 2 (DDR) * 8bytes/transfer (64-bit width) = 14.4GB/s

The observed (utilized) memory bandwidth in this case is given by the number on the link between "L2 Cache" and "Device Memory": 856.7MB/s (ie. less than 1GB/s)

> how could i know if i am achieving the max memory throughput i can get from this card or not?

If you compare these two numbers, you'll get an idea.  However the peak theoretical bandwidth calculation above is generally not observable under any circumstances.  A better proxy for what is achievable as a maximum by "real" codes is given by the cuda bandwidthTest sample code, specifically referring to the "device-to-device" bandwidth measurement.  In any event, this number should still be in the several gigabytes per second range (perhaps 10, for your device) so you still have some headroom.

> is there a percentage value like occupancy but for memory throughput?

The profilers have [metrics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference) such as `dram_utilization` which may be of interest.  You could also aggregate `dram_read_throughput` and `dram_write_throughput` to get a more precise number.

Comment: what about the number on the link between "L1/Tex cache" and "shared memory"?  is there any information i can get from my GPU to used it in a calculation like the one you used with global memory or does it constant for the all GPU with same compute capability (Fermi 2.0, Kepler 3.0, Maxwell 5.0 .. )

Comment: I don't see any link between "L1/Tex cache" and "shared memory"

Comment: i mean the numbers on each one of them sir, can i make a meaning from them like you did with the number on Device memory link?

Comment: As far as I know, peak theoretical bandwidth to L1 or shared mem is unpublished.  However you can estimate what these would be based on the fact that either one can serve up at least a 128 byte cacheline every 2 GPU clocks (perf may be better than that - this may depend on the specific GPU).  In any event, these numbers are usually much higher than the  device memory bandwidth, in the TB/s range when aggregated across SMs (L1 cache and Shared are a per-SM resource).

Comment: You may also want to refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/memorystatistics.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.2%7CAnalysis%2520Tools%7CCUDA%2520Experiments%7CKernel-Level%2520Experiments%7CMemory%2520Statistics%7C_____0) for this page.